# Need Help Understanding and Figuring out Data Passing Datalists in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html-datalist

I'm fairly new to AngularJS and I'm trying to get data selected from this Datalist option to pass to my javascript function using AngularJS, but I'm getting nothing to come through for my Datalist inputs. I'm listing the option of the object Customer by it's property cust.Name, but I want to pass it's cust.ClientID as a parameter to the AngularJS function call to construct a new System. Instead when an option is selected and a System is trying to be built, the value for an input that contained a Datalist results in a default value of 0 and not the actual cust.ClientID value.

(*Here is an example of my code, edited to remove sensitive details.)

**HTML**

```
<div id="systemInfo" ng-controller="HomeController" class="container">
    <form name="systemForm" class="new-system-form  col-md-6">
        <div class="row submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Add New System" 
                ng-disabled="systemName == null
                  || cust == null
                  || freq == null
                  || stage == null
                  || allowOverDueHours == null
                  || fileCheckFrequencyHours == null
                  || overLapDays == null
                  || overLapDaysInterval == null
                  || overLapDaysIntervalWide == null
                  || messageResendIntervalHours == null"
                ng-click="createSystem(systemName, cust.ClientID, freq.Value, stage.StageID, allowOverDueHours, fileCheckFrequencyHours, overLapDays, overLapDaysInterval, overLapDaysIntervalWide, messageResendIntervalHours, isDifferential, compressFilesBeforeMove, runTamperValidation, runAddressParsing, runPC, runCleanReadings, runPPSPostProcessCleanup, runEntityEventValidation)"
                class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>

        <div class="fieldRow row">
            <label for="customer" class="col-form-label">Customer Name</label>
            <input list="customers" ng-model="cust" type="text" name="customer" id="customer" class="form-control">
            <datalist id="customers" name="customers">
                <option ng-repeat="cust in customers" name="customers" value="{{cust.Name}}"></option>
            </datalist>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.createSystem = function (name, clientID, frequency, stageID, allowOverDueHours, fileCheckFrequencyHours, overLapDays, overLapDaysInterval, overLapDaysIntervalWide, messageResendIntervalHours, isDifferential, compressFilesBeforeMove, runTamperValidation, runAddressParsing, runPC, runCleanReadings, runPPSPostProcessCleanup, runEntityEventValidation) {
    $http.post('../Data/CreateSystem', {
        name,
        clientID,
        frequency,
        stageID,
        allowOverDueHours,
        fileCheckFrequencyHours,
        overLapDays,
        overLapDaysInterval,
        overLapDaysIntervalWide,
        messageResendIntervalHours,
        isDifferential,
        compressFilesBeforeMove,
        runTamperValidation,
        runAddressParsing,
        runPC,
        runCleanReadings,
        runPPSPostProcessCleanup,
        runEntityEventValidation
    })
        .then(function (d) {
            console.log("system creation successful. new systemid = " + d.data);
            $window.location.href = '../Home/System?systemid=' + d.data;
        });
};
```

I'm trying to get each option in the datalist to keep its styling, it's styling is linked to a Bootstrap scaffolding for <input> tags. Yet, when the button on the site labeled, "Add New System" is pressed, I get a value of 0 for *clientID*, when it should read a valid nondefault value.

[image]

**JSON version of my customers[] object**

```
[
  {
    "ClientID": "-1",
    "Name": "Global Data",
    "CustDBServerName": "NA",
    "CustDBName": "NA",
    "InvstgtDBName": "NA"
  },
  {
    "ClientID": "42",
    "Name": "customer2",
    "CustDBServerName": "server2",
    "CustDBName": "C2",
    "InvstgtDBName": "C2"
  },
  {
    "ClientID": "86",
    "Name": "customer3",
    "CustDBServerName": "server3",
    "CustDBName": "C3",
    "InvstgtDBName": "C3"
  },
  {
    "ClientID": "1145",
    "Name": "customer4",
    "CustDBServerName": "server4",
    "CustDBName": "C4",
    "InvstgtDBName": "C4"
  },
  {
    "ClientID": "1146",
    "Name": "customer5",
    "CustDBServerName": "server5",
    "CustDBName": "C5",
    "InvstgtDBName": "C5"
  },
  {
    "ClientID": "1147",
    "Name": "customer6",
    "CustDBServerName": "server6",
    "CustDBName": "C6",
    "InvstgtDBName": "C6"
  },
  {
    "ClientID": "1148",
    "Name": "customer7",
    "CustDBServerName": "server7",
    "CustDBName": "C7",
    "InvstgtDBName": "C7"
  },
  {
    "ClientID": "1149",
    "Name": "customer8",
    "CustDBServerName": "server8",
    "CustDBName": "C8",
    "InvstgtDBName": "C8"
  },
  {
    "ClientID": "1151",
    "Name": "customer9",
    "CustDBServerName": "server9",
    "CustDBName": "C9",
    "InvstgtDBName": "C9"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of your option tags, is the name of the customer. I mean value="{{cust.Name}}". And you set that value into the cust variable in the scope. I mean ng-model="cust". Then it's very normal that you don't have a cust.clientID because when you select an option, cust will just be a string. There's no cust.clientID.

Comment: ok, so you're saying, I need to make my ng-model="cust.ClientID" to pass the ID number out? How would I display the cust.Name value in each Option so the user can read the name of the client, but only pass the cust.ClientID to the $scope? I'm new to AngularJS, can you write an example code or rephrase? Thanks :)

Comment: Try                 <option ng-repeat="cust in customers" name="customers" value="{{cust.clientID}}">{{cust.Name}}</option> or use ngOptions with select instead of datalist. Check out https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: When I use value="{{cust.ClientID}}">{{cust.Name}}...  I just get the integer values of the ID listed for the user to read as the options in the Datalist. Nothing is displayed with cust.Name. Also, when passed to the constructor, the ClientID value is now undefined instead of a default value of 0.

Only reason I don't want to use a Select in lieu of a Datalist is because my acceptance criteria states the user needs a way to type in the input box some characters that will filter out all the customers in the combobox. Standard behavior of the Datalist.

Comment: What does your customers array look like? Just put <pre>{{customers | json}}</pre> in the end of your html and reload the page. Then share the structure of the customers object please. Or create a sample code for us to be able to work on it!

Comment: Ok final solution:     <option data-value="{{cust.ClientID}}" value="{{cust.Name}}"></option> and be careful: your input tag is not closed, close it like that /> not just >

Comment: ok posted the redacted JSON of customers, and I'll give that suggestion a try right now, thanks Onur!

Comment: I tried that <option ng-repeat="cust in customers" data-value="{{cust.ClientID}}" value="{{cust.Name}}"></option> and the dropdown for the datalist in the UI only displays the ClientID's and not the names. I need the names displayed for the user to read on the options, but what they select should pass the the ClientID to the constructor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222265/discussion-between-matthew-jett-and-onur-basturk).